# Remove selected option with parentsUntil

Tags: jquery

I may be going about this the wrong way. I have a container of links and form options. When clicking on links it selects an option. In order to deselect the option if another is selected I need to iterate up the parent elements until a specific class and then remove the selected value for that option.

Here is some of the HTML.

```
<ul class="cssClass">
  <li><div class="first-elem">Select<span></span></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#firstValue">First Value</a></li>
        <li><a href="#secondValue">Second Value</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <select name="someSelect">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="firstValue">First Value</option>
        <option value="secondValue">Second Value</option>
    </select> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the start of the jQuery. Everything is working except my removeAttr part so I have excluded the rest.

```
$(".cssClass li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parentsUntil('.cssClass','option').removeAttr("selected");
```

But this is not working. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Could you show some sample mark-up, to make sense of the jQuery?

Comment: Updated. Everything is working except the removeAttr part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of [parentsUntil](http://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) is to filter, not to make a selection query.
Better use this

```
 $(this).closest('.cssClass').find('option').removeAttr("selected");
```

Comment: You have saved my sanity, I had a find earlier, but I didn't use closest. Doh! I can go home now. Thanks. For other people posting direct selectors, these would remove all the option values, not just the containing class where the anchor was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of parentsUntil isn't correct. It should look like this:

```
 $(this).parentsUntil($('ul.cssClass'), 'option').removeAttr("selected");
```

The [parentsUntil](http://api.jquery.com/parentsuntil/)'s first parameter should be:

> A string containing a selector expression to indicate where to stop matching ancestor elements.

Your second parameter would be fine, however, it doesn't appear that the select statement would actually find any options along the way to remove since the second parameter isn't a `.find`, but a filter.
So you may need to use something different altogether, something like:

```
$('ul.cssClass option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the markup but perhaps if you try to get to the thing in another way:

```
$("#theselectbox option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Give that mark-up:

```
$(".cssClass li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('select[name="someSelect"]').find('option[value="' + this.href.substring(1) + '"]').prop('selected',true);
});
```